# Active Admin with carrierwave

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, carrierwave

I am using active admin with carrier wave.
I am facing problem in uploading image using active admin.
I already have an image in my `public/img` folder named as banner.png.
Now I want to override that image with another image via admin panel.
When I upload image it shows me the parameters as below:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"iHI02QCklnooY2WvKOAI/OUPi6phmvVsYnXuRzvXg2Q=", "home_banner"=>{"home_banner_image"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xd8f728c @original_filename="Penguins.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"home_banner[home_banner_image][image]\"; filename=\"Penguins.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20140612-18313-18qw3aj>>}}, "commit"=>"Update Home banner", "id"=>"539981982131fc9c0e000002"}
```

But it does not save image in the database.

Here is my model and uploader

model:-

```
class Banner
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
 include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

 field :banner_image, type: String
 mount_uploader :banner_image, BannerUploader
end
```

Uploader:-

```
require 'open-uri'
require "digest/md5"
require 'carrierwave/processing/mini_magick'
class BannerUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

 storage :file

 def store_dir
  # "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  "/public/img"
 end

 def extension_white_list
  %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
 end

 # Override the filename of the uploaded files:
 # Avoid using model.id or version_name here, see uploader/store.rb for details.
 def filename
  "banner.png" if original_filename
 end
```

end

And my activeadmin for in admin folder is :-

```
ActiveAdmin.register Banner do

 index do                            
  column :banner_image                              
  default_actions                   
 end 

 form(:html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|
  f.inputs "Banner Image" do
   f.semantic_fields_for :banner_image do |fi|
    fi.input :image, :as => :file
   end
  end
  f.buttons
 end 
end
```

I am using mongoDb and my requirement is like I already having an image in public/img folder now to update that via admin so that it automatically gets reflected at front end without making any change in view code.

Please get involved in this question .
A big thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having same problem , did you solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

I can't guaranty for this, it's just from my mind and not tested:

For older ActiveAdmin version's 0.6 and 1.0 before ~ Okt./Nov. 2014

```
f.input :header_image, :as => :file, :hint => f.template.image_tag(f.object.image.url(:thumb))
```

For ActiveAdmin 1.0 after ~ Okt./Nov. 2014

```
f.input :header_image, :as => :file, :hint => image_tag(object.image.url(:thumb))
```